# How do you predict future values with this LSTM-RNN model I've built below?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have successfully created the model, and it works good on the test data. I don't know how to make it predict future values, can someone help me? I have tried changing the timestep to a negative value, so that the model  predicts future values, but I wasn't able to carry it out because I got errors that led me in a circle. Any help would be appreciated! Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset_train = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\file_train.csv', error_bad_lines = False)
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
sc_training_set = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range (1, 389):
    X_train.append(sc_training_set[i-1:i, 0])
    y_train.append(sc_training_set[i, 0])

X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 256, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 512, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 256, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 128, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 200, batch_size = 32)

dataset_test = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\file_test.csv', error_bad_lines = False)
stock_values = dataset_test.iloc[:, 1:2].values

total_dt = pd.concat((dataset_train['Open'], dataset_test['Open']), axis = 0)
inputs = total_dt[len(total_dt) - len(dataset_test) - 1:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1, 1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []

for i in range(1, 364):
    X_test.append(sc_training_set[i-1:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

pred_stock = regressor.predict(X_test)
pred_stock = sc.inverse_transform(pred_stock)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I am using something like this in my code 
First you need to mention how many values you want to predict(I used 168)

```
n_ahead=input("How many values do you want to predict ?");
n_ahead=int(n_ahead)
# Making the prediction list 
def predict_ahead(n_ahead):
   yhat = []
   for _ in range(n_ahead):
   # Making the prediction
       fc = regressor.predict(X_train)
       yhat.append(fc)

   # Creating a new input matrix for forecasting
       X_train = np.append(X_train, fc)

   # Ommitting the first variable
       X_train = np.delete(X_train, 0)

   # Reshaping for the next iteration
       X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (1, len(X_train), 1))

   return yhat 
p=predict_ahead(n_ahead)
print(p)
```

Do keep in mind that X_train is an array and you need to reshape it during every iteration as input to LSTM

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Comment: Great, please let me know what happens

Comment: I get an error, can you help me with it? It gives me ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Which line blows up ?

Comment: On googling your error, I find this                                                                          The error message invalid literal for int() with base 10 would seem to indicate that you are passing a string that's not an integer to the int() function . I suggest you look at the first 2 lines . Honestly, I didn't run it myself so I'll have to try it

Comment: I dont know, but everytime I try running it I get an error

Comment: Vincent, can you share your file ? I would like to run your code

Comment: Do you mean excel file, and code, because I haven't saved it into an h5py file yet.

Comment: Yeah, the csv file if you can

Comment: [link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AZN.ST/history?p=AZN.ST)

Comment: I saw the link but sorry, if you could share the excel file, that would be better for me

Comment: I don't know hw to share an excel file

Comment: Have you tried dragging the excel file to the comment bar ?Or googling it ?Maybe that will help you . Because I opened the link, copied the data but when i tried to read it, it was very difficult

Answer (score 1):

If your model works good on test data, so you trained it successfully. If it doesn't work on real world data, it seems your dataset is biased or your model is underfitted.
That's it. There is no need to review code.

Comment: It does work on real world data, because the test data is real world data. The problem is, that future predictions can't have underlying data, the real world data, so I can't use the model to predict the future data because there isn't any data on the future. But thanks for your answer though.

Comment: If it works on real world data. It should be work on next predictions tests such as future tests. Probably your nature of signal is none stationary and it's probability distribution varies over time. Your model is not as strong as enough to predict hidden dynamics.

Comment: Yes, I believe it works perfectly fine, but I don not know how to test it on future data.